# GCC C code compiling

Tags: gcc, paths, compiler

I have a problem regarding gcc. Although I have a background programming in C, I have never actually used gcc. Until now that is. I have a Go program I am creating, that uses a library (Fyne) that in turn requires the use of gcc for cross compiling. I am cross compiling to the ARM based Raspberry Pi 3, from my Ubuntu 18.04 x86 machine. I am able to cross compile just fine without gcc, but unfortunately that is not an option if I wish to use this particular library

When I attempt to build my Go program, I get an error, stating that Xlib.h cannot be found. This is strange, as the path it shows in the error appears to be mostly correct (I can't see it in entirety, as there are a number of /../.. in the beginning, however the part of the path that I can see, is correct)

I have spent the better part of 2 days trying to sort this extremely frustrating problem out. The file is clearly there (it's a C header file, that I can open in Notepad++)

I want to change or add to the compilers path that it searches. I found this resource online, that speaks about a number of Environment Variables, including one called COMPILER_PATH

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html

The document tells you about all the variables, however nowhere is there any information as to how to invoke or edit any of these variables. I have tried typing them in the command line (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04) or using them as a parameter for the gcc compiler itself, but none of this works.

How do I change or add to the compilers path?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. `COMPILER_PATH` is used as a search path for *subprograms* - the header file search path is usually set by `-I` on the gcc command line.